# Retrieve view Informations 1010data

Tags: api, 1010data

I have a view in my 1010data base and it has created by someone else  I want to identify its description and is their a direct api call to get that information.

Already tried with following Commands. it gave following errors.

```
using dir api endpoint.

<out>
    <rc>15</rc>
    <msg>Not a directory: xxx.views.test</msg>
</out>

using tabinfo endpoint.

<out>
    <rc>22</rc>
    <msg>Not currently implemented for Quick Query: XXX.views.test</msg>
</out>
```

Is their a command to see the structure of view and related tables?

I can retrieve column names using querydata api end point but i cannot get informations related to linked tables.

Is their a command or endpoint to get this information. 
Something like Show create view in Mysql :)

Comment: Just of curiosity, since I've noticed you posting a lot of 1010 data questions lately, does 1010 data have their own support system?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Yes they may have. but at the moment we don't have 1010 support because i'm doing some research on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried gettab ?
documentation is here: 
https://www2.1010data.com/documentationcenter/beta/XMLAPI/TableManagement/XMLAPI-gettab.html
It says there "If the table is a query (i.e., type is VIEW, PARAM, MERGED or TOLERANT) then the tab element will contain ops and dependencies elements. Any dependencies on other tables (i.e., links, merges) are available in the  element, which contains a list of table references if the table is a Quick Query or a merged table."

Can you please confirm if that works for you?
Thank you!